# Creating polygons/polylines from origin points using Python in ArcGIS?

Tags: python, math, arcgis, point, arcpy

I am still very new to Python. I am heading a project to map the building footprints within our county on the tax map.

I have found a previous question that may be very helpful for this project: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/creating-line-of-varying-distance-from-origin-point-using-python-in-arcgis-deskt

Our Cama system generates views/table with the needed information. Below is an example:

```
PARID    LLINE    VECT                     X_COORD    Y_COORD
1016649  0        R59D26L39U9L20U17        482547     1710874

                  180,59,270,26,0,39,90,9,0,20,90,17 (VECT column converted)
```

I have found some python examples to convert the VECT column, which are distance and direction calls to angles and distances separated by commas.

***My question:*** Is there a way to implement a loop into the script below to utilize a table rather than static, user entered, numbers? This would be very valuable to the county as we have several thousand polygons to construct.

Below is the snippet to change the distances and angles to x, y points to be generated in ArcMap 10.2

```
#Using trig to deflect from a starting point
import arcpy
from math import radians, sin, cos

origin_x, origin_y = (400460.99, 135836.7)
distance = 800
angle = 15 # in degrees

# calculate offsets with light trig
(disp_x, disp_y) = (distance * sin(radians(angle)),\
                    distance * cos(radians(angle)))
(end_x, end_y) = (origin_x + disp_x, origin_y + disp_y)

output = "offset-line.shp"
arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management("c:\workspace", output, "Polyline")
cur = arcpy.InsertCursor(output)
lineArray = arcpy.Array()

# start point
start = arcpy.Point()
(start.ID, start.X, start.Y) = (1, origin_x, origin_y)
lineArray.add(start)

# end point
end = arcpy.Point()
(end.ID, end.X, end.Y) = (2, end_x, end_y)
lineArray.add(end)

# write our fancy feature to the shapefile
feat = cur.newRow()
feat.shape = lineArray
cur.insertRow(feat)

# yes, this shouldn't really be necessary...
lineArray.removeAll()
del cur
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your valuable time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of dictionaries from given table that would hold all the different values. Such as

```
d = {1:{"x":400460.99,"y":135836.7,"distance":800,"angle":15}, 
     2:{"x":"etc","y":"etc","distance":"etc","angle":"etc"}}


for k in d.keys():
    origin_x, d[k]["x"]
    origin_y = d[k]["y"]
    distance = d[k]["distance"]
    angle = d[k]["angle"]

    #rest of the code
    #.....
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Would each line for every polygon need its own dictionary to be created? As mentioned in the question, we have several thousand polygons to create. @Daniel

Comment: @MichaelCore Yeah if the data is coming from a table you can assign a polygon id and then create a dic with its attributes. You'll have to create the dic of dics dynamically as well and not manually.

Comment: Great thank you for the insight. I will check out some cookbooks and help files and see what I can generate. I will post my code and mark your answer as soon as I have something useful to share. Thank you very much @Daniel